# How to prevent number input with decimals from hiding trailing zero on arrow click?

Tags: html, vue.js, validation, input

Project basically has a custom implementation of `<input type="number" step=".01" />` for currency. Wants to make it so there are always, always two decimals showing. Problem is that when using the arrows, the behavior of the input rounds to the nearest tenth. So clicking the arrow up from value `.09` to value `.10` will only show `.1` . I was able to half-negate this by adding a `.toFixed(2)` to the modelValue update (Vue) but when the user updates the number by clicking the little arrows, it still briefly shows the rounded value and they have to click off the input in order to get the correct value.

How do I make it so that clicking the arrows of the number input always shows at least two decimal places, even if it's a zero?

Comment: Answer posted.  I realize though you said you made a custom implementation of the input element, so there may still be something else in your custom component delaying the update. If the answer doesn't help, you'll need to provide more implementation details and actual code.

Answer (score 0):

> they have to click off the input in order to get the correct value

Sounds like maybe you're listening to the `change` event, whereas the `input` event should have an immediate effect.

Assuming Vue 3...

```js
<script setup>
import { ref } from 'vue'

const amount = ref('0.00')

function update(evt) {
  amount.value = parseFloat(evt.target.value).toFixed(2)
}
</script>

<template>
  <input type="number" step="0.01" :value="amount" @input="update" />
</template>
```

[Vue Playground](https://play.vuejs.org/#eNp9UctOwzAQ/BXLl7ZSlRZ6q1LEQ60EB0DA0ZeQbIqLY1v2OgRV+XfWTls4oN68M7OjGe+e31ibtQH4kue+dNIi84DBXgktG2scsj1zULOe1c40bETSkdBCl0Z7ZEVjgka2ipLxaJ7N56NJZOugS5RGs2CrAmEMLU7YXmh22MjaQgWgPVs4DxtlCoyaDAu3hQM7ydBsZAfV+JI8e6Hz2RCQotGA0FhF3jQxlkttAzL8trASXIfmHZzgzCNYminXBU3LZEvzkIGQ67RGyBCTkBnZ5bOTN59y9FS1ltts542mX0otBC9NY6UC92RjTy/4cugXuUIp8/WQMHQBpke8/IDy8x9857uICf7swINrKciJG35koNevj9DR+0Q2pgqK1GfIF/BGhZhxkN0GXVHsP7qU9j7dWurtm193CNofS8WgUdknveB0/7sz1X/jLrJF2qPT8f4Hb6HN0A==)